# For each employee, how many times have they been recommended for a discretionary raise?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables one called tblPerformanceReview and one called tblEmployee. I am trying to figure out how many times each employee has been recommended for a discretionary raise. tblPerformanceReview has a column called Discretionary which lets you know whether the employee was recommended for the raise of not. If they were recommended there would be a 1 if not there would be a 0. I am trying to find a way to count how many times each employee was recommended for a raise. I wanted it to display the Employee's first name and the count of how many times they were recommended for a raise. Both tables are connected through a field cold IDEmployee.

Sample code that gives me an error

```
    SELECT tblEmployee.FirstName,COUNT(tblPerformanceReview.Discretionary) 
FROM tblPerformanceReview,tblEmployee INNER JOIN 
tblEmployee 
ON tblPerformance.IDEmployee=tblEmployee.IDEmployee WHERE Discretionary='1' 
group by IDEmployee;
```

Comment: The group by column should also be in the select list.

Comment: *gives me an error* is not a problem description unless you include information about what that error is specifically.

Comment: I keep on getting the error ambiguous column name: tblEmployee.FirstName

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your query references three tables, but one is missing from the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `tblPerformance` should really be `tblPerformanceReview` in your query.

I believe you want:

```
SELECT e.IDEmployee, e.FirstName, 
       COUNT(pr.Discretionary) 
FROM tblEmployee e LEFT JOIN
     tblPerformanceReview pr
     ON pr.IDEmployee = e.IDEmployee AND
        pr.Discretionary = 1
GROUP BY e.IDEmployee, e.FirstName;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases to the query is easier to read and write.
- This uses a `LEFT JOIN`.  Your question implies that you want all employees, not just those that have at least one discretionary raise.
- The `'1'` looks like a number, so I dropped the quotes.  If the column really contains a string, keep the string.
- Employees can have the same first name, so I included the `idEmployee` in both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
    SELECT tblEmployee.FirstName,COUNT(*) 
FROM tblPerformanceReview INNER JOIN 
tblEmployee 
ON tblPerformance.IDEmployee=tblEmployee.IDEmployee WHERE Discretionary='1' 
group by tblEmployee.FirstName;
```

Comment: This code did not work I got an error saying ambiguous column name: tblEmployee.FirstName

Comment: I fixed it. Run it again

Answer (score 1):

try removing the ",tblEmployee" portion from the "FROM tblPerformanceReview,tblEmployee INNER JOIN" statement.  The rest of your query looks correct.